# How do I export a spreadsheet (csv) in excel using ascii control characters as the delimiters?

Tags: ruby, excel, export-to-csv

I have this csv file that I would like to parse with Ruby.  The file's data is a cluster with commas and new lines in the fields but Excel still reads it properly. If the file could be exported from excel using the unit and record separators as the delimiters for the columns and rows, I'd be golden.

Anybody know how to specify those characters in excel? Thanks!

Comment: You can't unless you write the file out using automation or OpenXML.  It would involve opening the .xlsx, iterating over the sheets, rows, cells (which can be ragged), and writing them to a file with the correct delimiters.  I.e., slow, brittle (formulas vs. values, etc.), and bound to be a hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having Google Sheets export the file as json.  [Steps I followed here](http://blog.pamelafox.org/2013/06/exporting-google-spreadsheet-as-json.html)  There were 10,000 records and the browser tab crashed when it tried to do all of them.  So I had to piece meal it.  I'm sure there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ruby CSV with this option:

> :col_sep
>
> The String placed between each field. This String will be transcoded
>   into the data’s Encoding before parsing.

See more here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html